# Can't write to firebase database while a user from firebase authentication is signed in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I followed tutorials to use Firebase authentication using the AuthUI.IdpConfig library -

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Logged in");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Not logged in");
        // Choose authentication providers
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build());

// Create and launch sign-in intent
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Successfully signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "Successful sign in");
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            Log.d(TAG, "The token is " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
            // ...
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Unsuccessful sign in");

            // Sign in failed, check response for error code
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that the following code does not update my firebase database...

```
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

    myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

Unless I first sign out using

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

My rules are set to 'true' for reading and writing to the database. Why does being signed in affect writing to the database?

Answer (score 0):

you need use .child() or push() to before setValue();

```
//List data
myRef.push().setValue()

//Simple data
myRef.child("key").setValue()
```

Comment: I do have a .push() version of this elsewhere in the code. The 'Hello World' is just a test to see whether I can write to the database at all... Which I cannot, unless I sign out first. So setValue() on myRef, even without .child() or .push(), does work.